# In VMware does a shared folder between a guest and host OS take room on both file systems?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, disk-space, shared-folders

Let's say I have a host system with a 100GB of free space and a guest system with 60GB of free space. In the guest system if I were to download a 1GB file and put it in a shared folder, how would this affect the free space of both systems? Would both, the  host, or the guest have 1 GB less of free space left?

Comment: You mention shared folder in the headline, but in the long description it's not there anymore. Is this still related to shared folders? As in do you download 1Gb file to a shared folder or just anywhere in a VM?

Comment: @edvinas.me silly me, updated

Answer (score 3):

Shared folders are stored on Host VM and should not impact guest's file size. To answer your question directly, if you download 1Gb file to a shared folder, only free space in Host system should decrease (to 99Gb), while guest's system should stay at 60Gb free.